# If the integral of $c/x$ is $c.log(x)+C$ what is the base?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

This question is a follow up to an answer I gave here: [What is the correct integral of $\frac{1}{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161248/what-is-the-correct-integral-of-frac1x/1888877#1888877) After the algebra I said that 'This step of course gives the argument of $\log(x)$ the value $e$... and note that so far we have not specified a base for $\log(x)$ - the proof is true using any logarithm. For convenience we therefore give $\log(x)$ the base $e$ and denote it $\ln(x)$; consequently $\ln′(x)=1/x$ but given another base the numerator would be different.' And then quoted wikipedia which said the same thing in a different way. However [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%2Fx+integral) says '$\log(x)$ is the natural logarithm' when they give the answer in the title. So who is wrong? And why?

EDIT - I did some tests using the following python3 script:

```
from math import log    #log is ln by default in python

#[c/(xp+ep) - c/xp]/ep = -c/(xp**2+ep*xp): finite derivative of 1/x
def numerint(a, b, c, eps):
    ep = (b - a)/eps    #one epsilon
    intg = 0            #the numerical integral
    xp = a              #the current x point
    for x in range(eps):
        intg += c/xp*ep - 1/2*ep**2*c/(xp**2 + ep*xp)
        xp += ep
    print('Numerical integral of 1/x:', intg)
    intgcalc = log(b) - log(a)
    print('ln(b) - ln(a):', intgcalc, intg/intgcalc)

numerint(0.5, 2.5, 3, 10000)
#The derivative is log(e)/x to any base, what base can be raised by c to yield e?
```

The objective is to see what happens when we change the third numerint argument, set at 3 above. The third print statement in this case gives 3; in general it gives c. This means that even though the base of the logarithm is undetermined we can write it as a natural logarithm and just multiply it by $c$ instead of writing it in a different base. Wikipedia: 'Logarithms can be defined to any positive base other than 1, not only e. However, logarithms in other bases differ only by a constant multiplier from the natural logarithm, and are usually defined in terms of the latter.'

Comment: The link to wolfram's answer does say that $\log x$ is the natural logarithm. I think natural log is always assumed in most cases.

Comment: Then why am I wrong? Surely it's only definitely the natural logarithm if $c=1$.

Comment: $\frac {d}{dx}\log_a(x)=\frac 1{x\ln(a)}$ .

Comment: Many more advanced math texts/articles always use $\log x$ to refer to the log base $e.$ On many calculators the "log" button is for log base 10 and "ln" button for log base e. It's all a matter of convention.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161248/what-is-the-correct-integral-of-frac1x?rq=1

Comment: [Sequel](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764187/is-the-natural-logarithm-actually-unique-as-a-multiplier)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base is the one that satisfies

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1x &= \frac{d}{dx}\log_a x\\
 &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log_a(x+h)-\log_a x}{h}\\
 &= \lim_{h\to0}\log_a\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{1/h}\\
 &= \lim_{h\to0}\log_a\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{x/hx}\\
 &= \frac1x\log_a\left[\lim_{h\to0}\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{x/h}\right]\\
\end{align*}$$

It happens that the limit is special enough to have a name $e$. If $a\ne e$, then there is an ugly scaling constant $\log_a e$ on the right hand side; otherwise, that constant $\log_e e = 1$.

So, $a$ is the base chosen to make $\frac{d}{dx}\log_a x$ free of scaling constants other than $1$.

Comment: I think you mean that if $a$ has a value other than $e$ it will take a value other than one to raise $a$ to $e$. That value would be $c$!

Comment: So you are talking about the constant $c$ in $\int \frac{c\ dx}{x}$? If I do not specify the base of the antiderivative, then 
$$\int\frac{c\ dx}x = \frac c{ \log_ae}\int\frac{dx\ \log_a e}x = \frac{c\log_a x}{\log_a e} + C$$
If $a\ne e$, then the antiderivative will not be free of scaling constants.

Comment: If by $c$, you mean the constant of integration then, no. Remember that the RHS is differentiating, not integrating. If we integrate the final RHS, we will get the original function, $\log_a x$

Comment: It's a lower case $c$ meaning any number, not the the constant of integration, that would be upper case.

Comment: @selfawareuser I am referring to your question title $$\int\frac{c\ dx}{x} = c\log_a x + C$$
In this case, $a = e$. If instead, the right hand side is $\log_a x + C$ without the little $c$, then yes, you can simplify by picking $a$ such that $$c = \log_ae$$

Comment: @peterwhy I think your equation is very similar to my interpretation of the wikipedia proof. The problem is it's also telling me that $∫ c/x=log_a x+C$ where $a$ is not necessarily $e$ (only when $c=1$) but I will have to check that carefully.

Comment: @selfawareuser How is that a problem?

Comment: @peterwhy It isn't, because of the unique property of natural logarithms! (See edit).

Answer (score 2):

It is the natural log! Think about it this way.

Let $y=\ln(x)$. It follows that $e^y=x$. From there, we can differentiate implicity; $y'*e^y=1$.
Now, $e^y=x$, so $x*y'=1$, and $y'=1/x$.

Comment: Seems like there are gaps in that reasoning. The last line in the linked answer is $ln'(x)=\frac{1}{x}ln(1+u)^\frac{1}{u}$ and the base for $ln()$ was never specified, so it could be any $c$.

Comment: @selfawareuser $\ln$ is the symbol for the log with base $e$.

Comment: I know, but I could replace $ln$ with $log$ in the proof (from wikipedia) and it remains valid.

Comment: @Neil The problem is with the statement $y'\ast e^y=1$. Differentiating $y$ and differentiating $e^y$ are not the same thing.

Comment: @selfawareuser Differentiating $e^y$ w.r.t. $x$ does give $e^y\ y'$.

Comment: @selfawareuser you use the chain rule